# Size of cached objects by SDWebImage

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ipad, sdwebimage

I wanted to calculate the current in-memory size occupied by SDWebImage (Not the max size of SDWebImage). During the application usage i need to track the current RAM allocation by SDWebImage cached objects.

Basically i wanted to calculate the size of all images (present at that time) in NSCache object.

How can i do this ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

I think this will return Memory Cache using given code.

Use `getSize` function of `SDImageCache.h`. Which returns in memory cache.

```
[[SDImageCache sharedImageCache] getSize];
```

Follow [SDWebImage](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/SDWebImage/3.3/Classes/SDImageCache.html#//api/name/getSize) for more details.

Comment: [[SDImageCache sharedImageCache] getSize] gives the disk cache size not the memory cache.

Comment: Just for reference, the retrieved size is in bytes.

Comment: `getSize` renamed to `totalDiskSize`.

Comment: where to get memory cache size?

Answer (score 2):

do you mean this, taken from `SDWebImageCache.h`:

```
/**
  * The maximum "total cost" of the in-memory image cache. The cost function is the number of pixels held in memory.
  */

  @property (assign, nonatomic) NSUInteger maxMemoryCost;`
```

then total number of bytes is number of pixels held in memory * number of bytes per pixel, in this case 4 Bytes/Pixel

Comment: The amount of RAM consumed by cache(at a given point of time) in bytes/KB.

Comment: From the maxMemoryCost , how can i calculate the memory allocated?

Comment: Is it always 4 Bytes/Pixel ? How do you determine number of bytes per pixel ?

Comment: I just tried [[SDImageCache sharedImageCache] maxMemoryCost] , but it return 0 !